# yq: how to read a sibling element value?

Tags: yaml, yq

I am exploring yq to modify my YAML where I want to add a new element under `spec` of the ImageStream with `name == openshift45`

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/component: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: openshift45
    name: nodejs-10
  spec:
    lookupPolicy:
      local: false
    tags:
    - annotations:
        openshift.io/imported-from: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-10
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-10
      generation: null
      importPolicy: {}
      name: latest
      referencePolicy:
        type: ""
  status:
    dockerImageRepository: ""
- apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/component: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: openshift45
    name: openshift45
  spec:
    lookupPolicy:
      local: false
  status:
    dockerImageRepository: ""
```

The below command returns the valid `metadata` element. Now, I want to move to the parent and then pick `spec`. Is this possible with `yq` - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq?

```
yq r openshift45.yaml --printMode pv "items(kind==ImageStream).(name==openshift45)"
```

returns

```
items.[1].metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: openshift45
    app.kubernetes.io/component: openshift45
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: openshift45
  name: openshift45
```

Expected output:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/component: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: openshift45
    name: nodejs-10
  spec:
    lookupPolicy:
      local: false
    tags:
    - annotations:
        openshift.io/imported-from: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-10
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-10
      generation: null
      importPolicy: {}
      name: latest
      referencePolicy:
        type: ""
  status:
    dockerImageRepository: ""
- apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/component: openshift45
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: openshift45
    name: openshift45
  spec:
    *dockerImageRepository: <$MYREGISTRY>/<$MYNAMESPACE>/<$MYPROJECT>*
    lookupPolicy:
      local: false
  status:
    dockerImageRepository: ""
```

Comment: What is the expected output you want to achieve?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, wanted to add a new element to spec of ImageStream with name openshift45

Comment: Yes, but please update the _exact_ output structure desired, rather than letting people assume the output

Comment: Updated my question with the expected output and also added \*...\* to the element to be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Path Expressions in mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/path-expressions) is not quite documented to show a real example of how to use multiple conditions to get to the desired object. So for the YAML in question, using one unique condition you could do something like below. Verified in `yq version 3.3.2`

```
yq w openshift45.yaml 'items.(metadata.name == openshift45).spec.dockerImageRepository' '<$MYREGISTRY>/<$MYNAMESPACE>/<$MYPROJECT>'
```

You can use the `-i` flag along with write to modify the YAML in-place. See [Updating files in-place](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/write-update#updating-files-in-place)

If this isn't desired and you need multiple conditional selection to get to the desired object, suggest raising a issue at the GitHub page - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues requesting the right syntax for the same.

Comment: Worked like a charm but I have to add `-i` to update the YAML `inline`

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli: Just added a note for the same

Comment: This is adding dockerImageRepository to all kinds(service, deployment etc.,). I am looking to add it to only ImageStream kind. Thanks

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli: I did add a note about that right? Multiple condition expressions is not quite documented in mikefarah/yq. Let me try it one more time

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli: Its not possible with yq as of now - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/513 also https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/557

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli: Can you use another variant of `yq` - One based on Python - with a wrapper over `jq`? - https://pypi.org/project/yq/. It is possible to implement with it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible in yq. You will have to get the output of first command in a variable and pass that variable to next one.

yq is a wrapper on jq but it doesn't have the functionality of custom functions. Custom functions make it possible to use any value from any hierarchy of the document at one place.

Thanks to Inian for pointing out that OP is not using the wrapper yq version. Unfortunately, the version used also doesn't allow using custom functions for now.

Comment: OP is using https://github.com/mikefarah/yq and not the python version which is a wrapper over `jq`. There are two versions of `jq` out there

Comment: @Inian, thanks for pointing out. Unfortunately, it also doesn't support custom functions.

Comment: You don't need custom functions, a right path expression should suffice. See my answer. Also as it stands, your answer might be confusing for future readers. So if you don't have a clear solution, suggest deleting this